# ValidationGroup fired after OnClick

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to do client-side validation to check if the textbox is empty before submit the form to server. However, the form is submit to server even though the textbox is empty.

```
<asp:Button ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="Submit Order" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                            ValidationGroup="DeliveryAddVad" OnClick="SbmtOrder_Click" Width="150px"  />
```

An error message will display under the textbox. 
Is there anyway can stop the form submit to server if the textbox is empty.
The concern is `OnClick="SbmtOrder_Click"` will display a dialog, I do not want the dialog to show up if the textbox is empty.

Comment: you need to include code of your text box controls and required field validators etc which related to this activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a [`RequiredFieldValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<asp:Button ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
    ValidationGroup="DeliveryAddVad"
    UseSubmitBehavior="False"
    Text="Submit Order" 
    CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  
    OnClick="SbmtOrder_Click" 
    Width="150px"  
/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="reqOrder" 
    ValidationGroup="DeliveryAddVad"
    controltovalidate="NameOfTextBox" 
    errormessage="Please enter [whatever the user has to enter]!" 
/>
```

You can also try to set [`Button.UseSubmitBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false` (edited above) and the [`TextBox.CausesValidation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.causesvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`(default false).

Comment: Thanks for your response.I've added RequiredFieldValidator , it is still the same.

Comment: @gladys: try to change the submit behaviour to false which means that ASP.NET does inject client-script to do the postback. You should also  set `TextBox.CausesValidation` to `true`. I've edited my answer accordingly.